# JavaFX Erratic behavior with Node.setOnMouseEntered/Exited

Tags: java, events, javafx, label, mouse

In my JavaFX project, I have a `ModifiedTreeCell` class which `extends TreeCell`. In that class, I have two functions which listen to whether the mouse enters or exits the TreeCell. However, these methods appear to be horrendously unreliable.

Either:

A) They don't detect the mouse entering at all and no popup occurs.

B) They keep calling `ENTERED` and `EXITED` back to back forever, so the popup flashes over and over.

C) They will detect an `Enter` and then immediately detect an `Exit` even though the mouse is still well within the boundary of the `Label`.

**How can I fix this?**

If you'd like to see what I mean first hand, I compiled a runnable Jar file of my project:

[Here is the repo](https://github.com/KevinTyrrell/Diablo2BankTracker). Once you download it, run `D2BT.jar` and make a new account, a new character, then add an item like `Ring`, click `Magic` from the `ChoiceBox`, and then click the Add Item `Button`. Go to the View Account Tree `Tab` to and then hover over one of the `Label`(s) in Blue.

Okay in the image below, I know my mouse cursor looks like it's on the edge of the `Label` but I'm telling you if you tried it yourself it doesn't really matter where your mouse is. The `setOnMouseEntered/Exited` commands simply don't work properly. I know it may seem like it's my `ItemFrame` `Popup` causing the problem but I assure you that it will occur even if you comment out the `frame.show();` and `frame.hide();` methods shown in the image.

[image]

Here is the `ModifiedTreeCell` class:

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import logic.Item;

/**
 * This TreeCell object is for the TreeCellFactory
 * function in the GUI class. The TreeCellFactory
 * function will convert TreeItem objects into
 * ModifiedTreeCell objects which display the 
 * necesary information to the user, such as
 * a Label displaying either the Account name, 
 * Character name, or Item in a readable fashion.
 * @author Kevin
 *
 */
public class ModifiedTreeCell extends TreeCell<TreeViewable>
{
    /**
     * This Label will display the neccesary text related to the item.
     * The Label may have a `on Mouse Hover` listener which will display
     * a ItemFrame_Animated IF the TreeViewable object claims it to be an item.
     */
    private Label displayProperty;

    @Override public void updateItem(TreeViewable value, boolean empty)
    {
        if (!empty)
        {
            setEditable(true);

            // Create the label for this cell.
            displayProperty = new Label(value.getTextProperty());
            displayProperty.getStyleClass().clear();

            // If Value is an Item object...
            if (value instanceof Item)
            {
                // Item Reference.
                Item ref = (Item) value;

                // Create a Popup window of the item hovered over.
                ItemFrame_Animated frame = new ItemFrame_Animated(ref);
                displayProperty.setFont(GUI.diabloFont);
                displayProperty.setTextFill(ref.getQuality().getColor());

                displayProperty.setOnMouseEntered(e ->
                {
                    System.out.println("MOUSE ENTERED THIS LABEL");
                    frame.show(GUI.window);
                });
                displayProperty.setOnMouseExited(e ->
                {
                    System.out.println("MOUSE EXITED THIS LABEL");
                    frame.hide();
                });
            }

            displayProperty.setStyle(GUI.DEBUG_PANE_BORDER);

            // Display a Node for this cell.
            setGraphic(displayProperty);
        }
        else 
        {
            // No cell to be displayed, set to null.
            setText("");
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally succeded compiling your project.
Result is no surprise -> by commenting the `frame.hide()` line, the popup stays on. A solution is given below at `3.`

Now some points you can apply to get a super duper app that will not become a mess very quickly.

1. Get a nice build architecture for your Java project. You can do this by organizing it as a Maven Project. This is just a suggestion, the point is that you should be very confident by fetching your resource files for instance (in your project, you do it by at least 2 or 3 different methods, using `File` class and `getResource(String path)` method.
2. Think more about your architecture before start coding. I am quite sure you did'nt think about any pattern or any idioma before. Think about how you can split your app in multiples mini-API that handle a specific part of logic. Moreover, the gap between your logic and the GUI should be moremore larger to avoid spaghetti code.
3. Read more tutorials about JavaFX. What you are trying to achieve with a Popup already exists and is called a Tooltip, you already use it in your app and it is as customizable as any other JavaFX component.

I hope you will succeed in a very usefull App for all Diablo2 gamers! :)

Comment: Hey man! I didn't have enough room here so I made a pastebin with my response: http://pastebin.com/0y6Ett9S

Comment: Response to your response is here : http://pastebin.com/6neVRTSH
If you want, please continue by mail so we don't flood SO :)